# Firebase setValue OutOfMemory exception

Tags: android, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read values from Sharedpreferences and update to firebase database. It worked really fine till yesterday. Now it suddenly started throwing OutofMemory exception in below code.

Code:

```
public void updateFirebaseDatabase(){
    save s = new save(this,Constants.USERDETAILS);
    int score= 1000;
    ref = new Firebase("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    ref.child("users").
    child(s.read(Constants.USERID));
    User alan = new User(s.read(Constants.DISPLAYNAME),s.read(Constants.EMAIL),s.read(Constants.PROFILE_URL),score);
    ref.setValue(alan, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
            if (firebaseError != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Score update error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: try to use the new Firebase SDK, guide is [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android)

Comment: Looks it is totally new. I will try it.

Comment: Given that nothing changed to the Firebase SDK that you're using in over half a year, it seems more likely that something else changed. If you didn't change the code (usually my prime suspect), what else *did* change? For example: did the data in the database change? Are you on a different network? Did you try uninstalling/reinstalling the app? Note that you will have to come up with such steps on your own, because StackOverflow is a very inefficient tool to help you troubleshoot issues like this.

Comment: I figured out the problem. problem is with the Setters/getters in the User class. Thank you for responding